# Registered users do not appear in the admin panel

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a project in Django where I am building a form so that users can register on the page; at the time of making a test registration of a user, I can not see the information of the same in the administration panel

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def registerPage(request):
    form_value = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form_value.is_valid():
            form_value.save()

    context = {'form_key':form_value}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

register.html

```html
<h3>Register</h3>

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form_key.as_p}}

    <input type="submit" name="Create User">

</form>
```

I don't know if I should register the view in "admin.py" to be able to see the users who do the registration.

Comment: This is covered in the [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin) tutorial.

Comment: Please read the help article on [formatting](/help/formatting). Abusing bold formatting on every single prose-character in your posts just makes people's eyes hurt and does not increase readability of your post one bit. Refrain from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the view along with the model in the 'admin.py' file.

Like this example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Django has built-in validators, which makes it necessary that you use corresponding passwords (like upper case and lower case letters and numbers) in setting.py file.

Comment: like letter(upper case and lower case) with numbers

Comment: I edited to make a readable version of what I guess you mean the answer to be. Feel free to undo my edit and instead yourself combine the post and the comment into an answer according to [answer], maybe by using this info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help